# Stopping node.js process on Mac

Tags: macos, node.js, bash, sockets

I have a `node.js` application that uses some socket ports. Sometimes, when I exit the application with `Ctrl + C`, some kind of node process is left running, still allocating the socket ports. Thus, I cannot restart my application, since it fails to open those ports. When I look the situation with `ps`, I get the following response:

```
$ ps

PID TTY           TIME CMD

40454 ttys000    0:00.11 -bash

41643 ttys001    0:00.00 (node)

41741 ttys001    0:00.00 (node)
```

Trying `kill -9 41643` doesn't kill the process. Is it a some kind of unkillable zombie? How can I get rid of those (node)-things blocking my `tcp` ports?

Answer (score 41):

I'm not a MAC user, but here is what I use to kill all the available node processes (under linux):

```
sudo killall -9 node
```

Answer (score 22):

On macOS, it's simply:

```
sudo killall -9 node
```

For a lot of the times, `sudo` is overkill, but in your case, it looks like you might want to try `sudo`.

Comment: Why the need of -9?

Comment: @CaioKawasaki without it, you're not going to pre-emptively kill the node process. Instead, you're letting the processes handle whatever the default signal is, which, there is a slight chance that they will handle the signal without actually killing themselves. Instead, with `-9`, you're flat out killing the processes, without letting them know.